# Cannot read TDMS file ('TdmsFile' object has no attribute 'xxx')

Tags: python, labview

I have trouble reading my tdms file from LabVIEW.

**1, Read my file from my path. It is ok to load it at this point.**

```
tdms_file = TdmsFile('/path/to/Env16-05-30-2021.tdms')
```

**2, Successfully see the group property:**

```
tdms_file.groups()
```

It returned:

```
[<TdmsGroup with path /'Measured Env Time'>,
 <TdmsGroup with path /'Measured Env Data'>]
```

**3, I can not access to group channels in one of my group:**

```
tdms_file.group_channels('Measured Env Time')
```

It returned:

```
'TdmsFile' object has no attribute 'group_channels'
```

**4, I already know my group_channels name and try to access it**

```
time = tdms_file.object('Measured Env Time', 'Time').data
```

It returned:

```
'TdmsFile' object has no attribute 'object'
```

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you use LabVIEW for it? Then why did you post `python` code? I'm confused, because now it is not clear what exactly does not work - LabVIEW code, or this `python` code. Please, if there are issues with file reading via LabVIEW - then post here LabVIEW code, and also TDMS file which you try to read.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post what python package you are using to read the TDMS file I will assume you are using the latest version of [npTDMS](https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/).

Looking at [its documentation](https://nptdms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apireference.html#module-nptdms) it seems you should access the channels of a group via

`group_channels = tdms_file[group_name].channels()`

Or if you already know the group and the channel you can just

`channel = tdms_file[group_name][channel_name]`